Will volatile formulas in conditional formatting cause a performance hit?
I currently have an Excel scheduling spreadsheet with a calendar/gantt chart.  This calendar is quite large (tens of thousands of cells) and has a lot of conditional formatting, including use of today() so that today's date is highlighted.  It is also suffering from performance issues that I want to address if possible.
My current understanding
In Excel, heavy use of volatile formulas (such as TODAY()) can cause large workbooks to slow down, as every time a change is made in the spreadsheet, all volatile formulas recalculate.
Conditional formatting also acts similarly to volatile formulas, where any change on the spreadsheet will cause all visible conditional formatting to reevaluate.
Right now I am assuming that using today() in conditional formatting will not suffer from the normal volatile-function issues because conditional formatting is already somewhat volatile.  Is this assumption correct?  Or would avoiding the use of conditional formatting formulas that rely on today() speed up the spreadsheet?  Any clearer details on how volatile formulas and conditional formatting interact would be helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Consider populating a single cell with TODAY() and referencing it in the conditional formats.

Thank you @cybernetic.nomad .   I definitely should've done that in the first place!  There is noticeable improvement after that change.  Additionally, I also changed today() into a non-volatile today using a workbook open macro like described here: https://trumpexcel.com/excel-volatile-formulas/

Volatile functions and formulas will always recalculate whenever any cell in the spreadsheet is changed. How many volatile formulas are in the spreadsheet then does not really matter, since the calculation is performed anyway.
Conditional Formatting, however, adds additional strain on the performance, since not only does the condition need to be evaluated after a data change (this is the volatility), but the rendering of the format also requires computing power.
Slowness caused by conditional formatting is additive: the more CFs you use, the slower your workbook will become.
Trying to avoid volatile functions in conditional formatting rules is rather pointless.
If you want to run performance tests on a particular file, I recommen you look for Charles Williams' Decisionmodels.com, which has a few free and paid for tools to identify the bottlenecks.
